# Angular 6 checkbox triggers change when ngModel value is true

Tags: angular, checkbox, angular6, angular-ngmodel

I have ngFor and inside I have checkbox.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-{{i}}"
  (change)="clickOn(test.fav)" [(ngModel)]="test.fav" />
```

**clickOn()** event triggers, when test.fav value is true. Anybody used to have this problem? Regards.

Comment: Do you mean it doesn't fire a `ngModelChange` event when value is `false`?

Comment: Or that it triggers initially, wihout any user action?

Comment: @PankajParkar I had to say (change). (change) function fires when checkbox ngModel value is true.

Comment: It triggers regardles of value.

Comment: @KoboldMines can you please provide me a stackblitz with reproducible problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use `reference` of checkbox element and pass the value or use `ngModelChange`

Replace the below code

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-{{i}}" (change)="clickOn(test.fav)" [(ngModel)]="test.fav" />
```

by

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-{{i}}" #test 
     (change)="clickOn(test.value)" [(ngModel)]="test.fav" />
```

or

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-{{i}}" #test 
     (ngModelChange)="clickOn($event)" [(ngModel)]="test.fav" />
```